# IIS shared configuration username

Tags: iis

I am trying to use a shared configuration from a team mate for IIS, however, I don't know what username/password to enter for the credentials. I've tried entering the encryption password that was used when he exported the settings. But I always get an error. What username should I be using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After watching this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3Je0a2v_5U

I found out that as long as your configuration directory is on your local machine (and not on a network drive), you don't put in a username OR password in the shared configuration page. After you hit "apply" in the "actions" sidebar, a window will pop up asking you what the encryption password is. Type in the same thing as the person that exported the setting and you're golden.

Hope this helps!